# Is there a way to produce an 'iterations left' count in a for loop after each iteration of the loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I've got a for loop where for each iteration, I either move a file or pass based on a user input. Sometimes my file list is huge and I want to know how many more iterations of the loop I have left. Is there a way to produce such a number? If I have to create another loop, where do I nest it?

```
for file in file_list:
   answer = input(f"Move it to {folder} or pass?: ")
      if "yes" in answer:
         shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
      if "no" in answer:
         pass
```

Is there a way to get this to print how many files I have left in my for loop after each user input?

Comment: What is `file_list`? If it is a list, you can use `len(file_list)` to get the number of items. You can use `enumerate()` to get the current index.

Comment: have you considered using enumerate(file_list) and then print the index in comparison to the length of file_list?

Comment: Do you know how many files there are when you start?

Comment: Thanks everyone, the creating a counter variable that increases for each file then printing the len(file_list) - counter worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a variable with the length of `file_list` and subtract 1 from it on each loop and print it:

```py
files_left = len(file_list)
for file in file_list:
   answer = input(f"Move it to {folder} or pass?: ")
      if "yes" in answer:
         shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
      if "no" in answer:
         pass
   files_left -= 1
   print("{} files left".format(files_left))
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks everyone!

Comment: That's great to hear! Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work